# What is the best way to map requirements to features in Redmine?

Tags: redmine

I am new to Redmine and I'd like to see if there is a good way to relate requirements (as stated by a product manager) to issues in Redmine.  To me it seems that a low impact way to do it would be to define a requirement tracker and then add a custom field with a list of links to feature tickets.
I have tried doing this but cannot figure out how to add a link within a custom field text box.

So I guess I have a general question and a specific question,

General) Is there a recognised recipe in the Redmine community to achieve a linkage from a requirement to a list of features or issues?

Specific) Can I create a link to another issue within an issue field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to both questions is to use the built-in mechanism to link issues - it's called *related issues*.

Once an issue is created, you can add link to an other issue and indicate the type of relation (related to, blocks, precedes, etc.)

To separate requirements and features by means of a different tracker seems good to me, expecially if you'd like to apply different permissions or workflows.

See also the redmine manual about [related issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssues#Related-issues), and an example of an issue with related issues http://www.redmine.org/issues/337

*EDIT*: More recently, [subtasks](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssues#Subtasks) have been added to redmine. They may be interesting to use in a scenario where a feature (issue) is implemented by means of different steps (=subtasks, like designing, programming, documentation,...) and/or by different persons (for example designer, programmer, ...).